# Changing layout when button clicked on widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-pendingintent, remoteview

I have a widget. What I want to do is to change a layout when button is clicked.

This is what I'm doing:

```
public class MainWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String ACTION_MENU_CLICKED = "MenuClicked";

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainWidgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_MENU_CLICKED);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_widget_layout);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_MENU_CLICKED)) {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_widget_layout);

            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.layout1,View.INVISIBLE);
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.layout2,View.VISIBLE);

            final int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        }
    }
}
```

Where is my problem? The code as it now does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onUpdate` update your code like this-

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_widget_layout);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);//you are missing this line.
```

and in your `onReceive` method replace `appWidgetId` with-

```
int[] appWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(
            new ComponentName(context, MainWidgetProvider.class));
```